# Get value by the array element name in json

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm not sure how to name these elements properly, it'll be easier just to show it. I have following JSON:

```
{
  "DEV": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd@asd.com"
    }
  ],
  "TEST": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd1@asd.com"
    }
  ],
  "PROD": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd2@asd.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the "DEV" by providing it's email. How to implement that in powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below can help -

```
PS> $json = '{
  "DEV": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd@asd.com"
    }
  ],
  "TEST": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd1@asd.com"
    }
  ],
  "PROD": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd2@asd.com"
    }
  ]
}' | ConvertFrom-Json

PS> ($json.psobject.Properties | ? {$_.Value -match "asd@asd.com"}).Name
```

Depending on the email matches you can retrieve the environment names.

Comment: Hi - can You help me on how did You know to check $json.psobject.Properties  
If You do `$json|get-member`  - it does not show that `$json` object has `psobject` property or method. What kind of property is it?

Comment: After the JSON has been converted, if you look at it's type, `$json.GetType()`, you will notice that it is a `PSCustomObject` deriving from the `System.Object` base class. All the `PS custom objects` will have the `PSObject.Properties` Property since it again derives from the `System.Management.Automation` namespace. See [the corresponding msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any elegant way of doing it. ConvertFrom-Json does not create neat objects with easy ways to traverse them  like convertfrom-xml, instead result is just a PsObject with bunch of noteproperties.
What I do in such cases is

```
    $a= @"
{
  "DEV": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd@asd.com"
    }
  ],
  "TEST": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd1@asd.com"
    }
  ],
  "PROD": [
    {
      "GitEmail": "asd2@asd.com"
    }
  ]
}  
"@
$JsonObject= ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $a 
$NAMES= $JsonObject|Get-Member |WHERE MemberType -EQ NOTEPROPERTY
$NAMES|Foreach-Object {IF($JsonObject.$($_.NAME).GITEMAIL -EQ 'asd@asd.com'){$_.NAME}}
```

Result of above is

```
DEV
```

Not pretty, not really re-usable but works. 
If anyone knows a better way of going about it  - I'll be happy to learn it:)

Comment: You have missing } in the code. However I choose another as a winner as it is single line solution

Comment: Thanks . have added the missing } to my answer.  
I agree the answer You choose is better. I'll be using that since now too :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise there is an easier method, but this here is one way:

Given that you json is stored in a variable `$json`:

You can get every head object with `$json.psobject.properties.name`:

**Input:**

`$json.psobject.properties.name`

**Output:**

```
DEV
TEST
PROD
```

With this we can create a `foreach` loop and search for the Email:

```
foreach ($dev in $json.psobject.properties.name)
{
  if($json.$dev.GitEmail -eq "asd@asd.com") {
    echo $dev
  }
}
```